# Overlay points on a ggplot line plot, without adding to the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given this example data frame:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
Site <- c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green")
Time <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-10-01", "2019-10-10", "2019-11-10", "2019-11-12", "2019-12-12", "2019-12-20", "2019-12-22", "2019-12-25", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-10", "2019-12-12", "2019-12-22"))
DepNum <- jitter(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2))
SS <-c("Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop")

DF <- data.frame(Site, Time, DepNum, SS)
```

I'd like to make a line plot with the DepNum variable, but then add points that would be colored by the second column (SS).

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Time, y = DepNum)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Site)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = SS))
```

[image]

When I make the above plot, the "Start" and "Stop" end up in the legend. I'd like to avoid having the "SS" variables end up in the legend (but keep the "DepNum" legend). I'd also like to specify the color of the points (AKA - green for "Start" points and Red for "Stop" points).

After researching this questions I found answers containing this: `geom_point(aes(col = SS), show.legend = FALSE)`. But this does not seem work:

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Time, y = DepNum)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Site)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = SS), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_point(color = ifelse(DF$SS == "Start", "green", "red"))`

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for requires two different color scales with different mappings. This is not possible in ggplot2 out of the box, but it can be done using the extension package ggnewscale. It provides the function `new_scale_color()` which allows you to define an entirely separate second color scale, with its own mapping and legend parameters.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

set.seed(1234)
Site <- c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green")
Time <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-10-01", "2019-10-10", "2019-11-10", "2019-11-12", "2019-12-12", "2019-12-20", "2019-12-22", "2019-12-25", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-10", "2019-12-12", "2019-12-22"))
DepNum <- jitter(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2))
SS <-c("Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop")

DF <- data.frame(Site, Time, DepNum, SS)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Time, y = DepNum)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Site)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(Blue = "blue", Red = "red", Green = "green")
  ) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(aes(color = SS), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(Start = "green", Stop = "red")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>